# Any way to improve this EF query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

In a WebApi which third parties consume, today we started experiencing failures when they call a method.

The method connects to a couple of tables and joins them. The error message from EF is

> > The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer Support Services for more information.

```
return context.leads
            .Where(q => q.eventID == 1234)
            .Join(context.config,
                leads => leads.configId,
                config => config.configId,
                (leads, config) => new { leads, config })
            .Where(p => keys.Contains(p.leads.leadId))
```

keys is a IEnumerable of retrieved lead ids. Basically we pull the list of ids and then we do the above, checking the keys collection so that our query returns accurate data.

keys holds about 28k ids.

Note that this has only started being an issue since migrating to Azure cloud, but I think that is a coincidence

Comment: EF has to create parameters for all the values in `keys` and I want to say there's a limit on that of around 2100.

Comment: Is `keys` an `IQueryable` by any chance?  If so then it's query will be nested into that one and maybe the issue is with how complex it is?

Comment: Your mechanism with keys is highly inefficient. Aside from juharrs comment, with an IEnumerable, you have to search through the entire list for every row you return that's 28k x # of rows. Is the keys list in the database? You'd be better off filtering there.

Comment: keys is IEnumerable<int> . Yes it is in the database

Comment: `keys is IEnumerable<int> . Yes it is in the database` <= so why not `Join` it the same way you did with `context.config` ?

Comment: @andrewb Yeah, so you should join it in the database. The where clause with IEnumerable.Contains will give you horrible performance the way you are doing it.

Comment: How can I use an IEnumberable in my EF query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help clarify on David's response:

What was the query you used to get the 28k IDs? That is the query you should merge into this query. Fetching IDs works fine for relatively small #'s of IDs, not 28k.  If you set up the relationships properly in EF you can avoid explicit joins. EF is not just a substitute wrapper for SQL. While you can write it with explicit joins between disconnected entities, it is a lot more powerful when set up as an ORM where the related entities know about each other. Your EF expression should look more like:

```
var leadsQuery = context.leads
    .Include(l => l.Config)  
    .Where(l => l.eventID == 1234
      && /* Insert criteria to determine which Leads to return. /*);
```

The where clauses to insert is *not* from an IEnumerable of IDs. That works fine for small numbers of rows. This should instead be the criteria you used to get those IDs.

A Lead should have a reference to a Config. No need to have DbSets declared for every table and then tell EF to join them. If a Lead table has a ConfigId then:

```
public class Lead
{
   //...
   public virtual Config Config { get; set; }
}
```

then if this is EF core, set up the mapping: (IEntityTypeConfiguration or OnModelCreating)

```
builder.Entity<Lead>()
  .HasOne(x => x.Config)
  .WithMany() // Lead has a config, Config does not have a collection of Leads.
  .HasForeignKey("ConfigId"); // Creates a shadow property for the FK.
```

or EF 6

```
builder.Entity<Lead>()
  .HasRequired(x => x.Config)
  .WithMany()
  .Map(x => x.MapKey("ConfigId")); // Similar to above. Set up the relationship without a FK in the entity, map directly to the table.
```

By using `.Include(l => l.Config)` you can access the lead.Config property to get the Config for that lead. There is no need to write queries to return leads and configs and other data separately. You do not need to `.Include()` related entities in order to query against them, however if you want to access those entities after the query through the properties, you should use `.Include()` to avoid extra lazy-load calls back to the database. (A powerful feature of EF, but an expensive one if not used carefully.)

Answer (score 2):

> keys is a IEnumerable of retrieved lead ids.
>
> keys holds about 28k ids.

So this:

```
return context.leads
            .Where(q => q.eventID == 1234)
            .Join(context.config,
                leads => leads.configId,
                config => config.configId,
                (leads, config) => new { leads, config })
            .Where(p => keys.Contains(p.leads.leadId))
```

will paste the IDs into the SQL Query text, like:

```
SELECT … WHERE LeadId in (1,23,3,4,5,6,45,34, . . . )
```

leading to large, non-reusable, and expensive-to-parse-and-compile query.  Better to load the IDs into a table and join them, or pass them to the server using XML, JSON or a Table-Valued Parameter.

> Basically we pull the list of ids and then we do the above

Then don't do that.  If the list of IDs you want is in the database, then join that in your query.  Avoid reading 28K IDs from the database and then sending them back in your query body.

Comment: So I have my ids in the Ienumerable<int> but how can I join on that?